# Pass an array to Flurry's setAge (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, flurry

I'm building an app for a client that has multiple age ranges for the user to optionally select. For example, I have a button labeled with an age range of 18-24. My question is, am I allowed to pass multiple integers in an array to `window.plugins.flurry.setAge();` ?

I have the following code:

```
var setAge = function(low,high) {
    var ageLow = low;
    var ageHigh = high;
    var age = [];  
    while(ageLow <= ageHigh){
        age.push(ageLow++)
    }
    window.plugins.flurry.setAge(age);
};

$('#set-age-one').on('click', function() {
    setAge(18,24);
});
```

When viewing Flurry's verbose mode in Xcode, I get confirmation that the values from 18-24 are indeed set properly. However, it's followed up by an error code of `AppName[31368:60b] -[__NSArrayM integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ae1bd10`

This doesn't terminate or break the app in any fashion, but I'm wondering if this will output properly to Flurry's Audience > Age section on the user dashboard. I could wait 6-8 hours for the dashboard to update and find out, but I'd rather know sooner than that.

**EDIT:** Here's a [link](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-flurry) to the plugin I'm using

Also, here's the full excerpt from Xcode:

```
2014-08-18 13:42:49.500 AppName[31904:60b] Setting Flurry Age to (
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24
)
2014-08-18 13:42:49.500 AppName[31904:60b] -[__NSArrayM integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10aa00760
```

**SOLUTION:**
In case anyone runs into this issue for their own project, the following logs a single integer for an age range:

```
var setAge = function(low,high) {
    var ageLow = low;
    var ageHigh = high;
    while(ageLow <= ageHigh) {
        window.plugins.flurry.setAge(ageLow++);
    }
};
```

Comment: can you provide the link to the plugin you are using? thanks.

Comment: I updated my original question with a link to the plugin, thanks

Comment: tldr; the xcode error is telling you that you cannot convert an array to an int. The method is expecting a single value, not an array of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the iOS code for the method `setAge` you can only pass a single value to the method. Even though the JS side accepts this as an array `[age]` this is only for the Cordova handler to pass data easily.

The iOS method is referencing:

```
int Age = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]integerValue];
```

Which simply states that it is converting the first index of the object into a true int. If you pass an array as the first index of the object the code will fail since it cannot convert an array to an int.

I would suggest changing `18-24` to `1824` so you can capture the age range as an int and then just pass that string instead of an array of int strings.

Additionally, if you need to capture all the values, you can recursively call the `setAge` for each value individually.